# Qt: Throwing an exception from C++ to QML engine

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

When calling a `Q_INVOKABLE` method written in `C++` from a `JavaScript` function in `QML`, how do you throw an exception ? The method is owned by an object of a type `< MyApp >` , registered with a call `qmlRegisterType()`

For example, I have the following QML code:

```
TextField {
    id: fld_recipient

    onEditingFinished: {
        try {
            var identity=myapp.identities.current_Identity;
            var company=identity.companies.current_Company;
            myapp.lookup_email(identity.identity_id,company.company_id,fld_recipient.text)
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the method MyApp::lookup_email() goes to the server and searches for matching email addresses. This process can be stopped by a large amount of errors and I want the catch() statement to show that error.

How is this done on the C++ side ? Kind of like this:

```
void MyApp::lookup_email(int identity_id,int company_id,QString email) {

    ....

    error_code=server->lookup_email(identity_id,company_id,email);

    if (error_code) { /// throw an exception to QML engine, 
         ????? <= what goes here ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Just return an empty string if an error occurs, and in QML check whether the string actually contains an email.

Comment: Also this http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-April/016652.html

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't bother dealing with exceptions, just use classical return code. It's not even about technology, but in my case I can't imagine myself thinking about some project year ago - oh damn.. where this exception coming from and where is it handled =)

Comment: @evilruff, I want to make it more friendly for the JavaScript developers who are going to use my component. The Q_INVOKABLE C++ method depends on other variables, and if, for example, they are NULL, I want to throw a TypeError saying that some variable is 'undefined'

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I was trying to do the same thing ...

Comment: @selbie, no I didn't pursue it. I am using Golang style of returning error object. Simple and proven approach. Exceptions are bad practice, I googled about it, and decided to drop this idea. You can return an "Error" object , previously registering it with qmlRegisterType or you can return error code. I am using a global Error object and returning error code (sort of like Linuxes `errno`) to avoid QML<--> C++ ownership problems.

Comment: Thanks Nulik. That's what I figured as well.

Answer (score 3):

Qml should not include any business logic but just display any results. In case your application runs into an exception state catch the exception in the business logic and present the resulting/new state to the user.

In case you assume your (UI) code will be called with incomplete data you should just ignore it. Or use assertions on debug level.

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet shows how you may use `QQmlEngine::throwError`:

```cpp
#ifndef __MathTools__
#define __MathTools__
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QString>
class MathTools : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MathTools(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
    Q_INVOKABLE double divide(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b == 0.0)
        {
            qmlEngine(this)->throwError(tr("Division by zero error"));
            return 0.0;
        }
        return a / b;
    }
};
#endif
```

When used in QML:

````
    ColumnLayout {
        TextField { id: first; text: "1" }
        TextField { id: second; text: "0" }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Divide")
            onClicked: {
                try {
                    const f = parseFloat(first.text);
                    const s = parseFloat(second.text);
                    result.text = mathTools.divide(f, s);
                } catch (err) {
                    result.text = err.message;
                }
            }
        }
        TextField { id: result }
    }```

I see a QML/Javascript error being thrown when attempting to divide by zero:
````

qrc:/main.qml:58: Error: Division by zero error

```
Reference:
 - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#throwError
```

Comment: Tried it like this in my QQuickItem subclass:
`QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine()->throwError(QJSValue::SyntaxError, "Custom Error Message");`

Doesn't do anything. What am I missing?

Comment: @mchiasson From the documentation, it looks like it doesn't act like a C++ throw, it will just trigger the JS exception when the control returns to the JS engine. In other words, use that in your topmost function.

Comment: @mchiasson I have updated my answer to show `qmlEngine(this)->throwError(...)`